# Limit function three variable $\lim_{\{x,y,z\} \to \{0,0,0\}} \frac{x y \sin(z)}{x^2+2y^2+3z^2}$- Wolfram alpha say that not exists

Tags: limits

I have to compute the limit 
$$
\lim_{\{x,y,z\} \to \{0,0,0\}} \frac{x y \sin(z)}{x^2+2y^2+3z^2}
$$

Using some parameter substitution to set some path (ex. y=bx, z=ax) i always get lim = 0. So it exists, if i'm not wrong, but wolfram alpha say that the limit is path dependent so it not exists.

How can i check for sure if the is a path where the limit is path dependent ?

Comment: Your test is only a necessary condition not a sufficient for the existence of the limit.

Comment: How can i verify the existence of the limit ?

Answer (score 1):

To show that the given limit is zero, we can use some inequalities. Now we apply inequality between arithmetic mean(AM) and geometric mean(GM):
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\ge \sqrt[n]{\prod_{i=1}^n x_i}\quad(x_i \ge 0)
$$
From the AM-GM inequality, we obtain $x^2+2y^2+3z^2 \ge 3 \sqrt[3]{6} |xyz|^{2/3} $. Suppose that $xyz\ne 0$. Then,
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{xy\sin z}{x^2+2y^2+3z^2}\right|&\le \left|\frac{xy\sin z}{3\sqrt[3]{6} (xyz)^{2/3}}\right|\\
&=\left|\frac{1}{3\sqrt[3]{6}}(xyz)^{1/3}\frac{\sin z}{z}\right|\\
&\le\left|\frac{1}{3\sqrt[3]{6}}(xyz)^{1/3}\right|.
\end{align}
The last inequality is obtained from $|\sin x|\le |x|$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. We first supposed that $xyz\ne 0$, but the inequality
$$
\left|\frac{xy\sin z}{x^2+2y^2+3z^2}\right|\le\left|\frac{1}{3\sqrt[3]{6}}(xyz)^{1/3}\right|
$$
holds for all $x,y,z\in \mathbb{R}$ except the case $x=y=z=0$. Since $\lim_{(x,y,z)\to (0,0,0)}(xyz)^{1/3}=0$,
$$
\lim_{(x,y,z)\to(0,0,0)}\frac{xy\sin z}{x^2+2y^2+3z^2} =0
$$
By the Squeeze Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively $$\left|\frac{xy\sin(z)}{x^2+2y^2+3z^2}\right|\le\frac{|xy|\cdot|\sin(z)|}{x^2+y^2}\le\frac{|xy|\cdot|\sin(z)|}{2|xy|}=\frac12|\sin(z)|.$$
Now, squeeze.